# I am trying to open Cypress in VS but keep getting this error message

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, cypress

Basically I get a error message saying that my command to open Cypress in visual studio timed out.

Comment: Can you add the error message? Which Cypress and Visual Studio versions you have installed? Which command are you using to launch? Screenshots, etc

Comment: Cypress verification timed out.

This command failed with the following output:

C:\Users\mic\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe --smoke-test --ping=965

----------

Command timed out after 30000 milliseconds: C:\Users\mic\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe --smoke-test --ping=965   
Timed out

----------

Platform: win32 (10.0.19042)
Cypress Version: 8.7.0

Comment: Version: 1.62.0 (user setup)
Commit: b3318bc0524af3d74034b8bb8a64df0ccf35549a
Date: 2021-11-03T15:23:01.379Z
Electron: 13.5.1
Chrome: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19042

Comment: node_modules\.bin\cypress open , this is the command I am using.

Comment: does my solutions below helped you?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, I tried solution 2 and I still get the same error saying the command timed out after 10000 ms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

You need to run `npx cypress verify`, there's a verification that's meant to happen for first-time users.

**Solution 2:**

To resolve this issue, you need to increase the `default timeout`. For this, go to below path: `node_modules\cypress\lib\tasks\verify.js`

Open `verify.js`, search variable `VERIFY_TEST_RUNNER_TIMEOUT_MS`. By default, it should be 30000. Change it to `100000`.

If neither solution is working, run the command `npm cache clean --force` to clean cache & rerun the steps again.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, I tried solution 2 and I still get the same error saying the command timed out after 30000 ms

Comment: Could you please run me through solution 1 step by step?

Comment: Cypress verification timed out.

This command failed with the following output:

C:\Users\mic\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe --smoke-test --ping=655

----------

Command timed out after 100000 milliseconds: C:\Users\mic\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\8.7.0\Cypress\Cypress.exe --smoke-test --ping=655
Timed out

----------

Platform: win32 (10.0.19042)
Cypress Version: 8.7.0

Comment: I'm getting the same error but after editing the variable in verify.js

Comment: Sure, you first run `npx cypress verify` and then rerun Cypress with `npx cypress open` in the project root folder.

Comment: I have tried this and I got the same error command timed out, I am still very new to software testing and I would be happy to jump on a google call if your available

Comment: Run `npm cache clean --force` to clean cache & rerun the steps again

Comment: Thanks I will try this now

Comment: Manuel you are a absolute star!! how do I give you a good rating/review? You have helped me so much. God bless you

Comment: Haha, thanks, bro! Happy to help! :) I'll update my answer as well to include `npm cache clean --force` for future reference.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm sure this will help so many people.